# CSS help for name and price alignment in Wordpress

Tags: css, price

I really need your help. I would like all my prices to show on the same line. Right now, the price shows below the product name, and depending on the length of the name, the price shows after.

Can I somehow force the prices to get aligned on the same line?

You can check http://dansupplies.dk to see what I mean. The first box has 4 products, and these prices should be on the same line.

My “related products” that show on the product page also needs this fix, if it’s possible of course.

Big high five!

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to other sites aren't adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to add a `min-height` to the `.woocommerce-loop-product__title` class.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD3wU.jpg)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input! Can you help on how the CSS code would look to add that? Wanna make sure I do it correctly :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks again!